# why in load-balancer with nginx, it doesnt find files in other servers?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

i setted up load balancing with nginx and apache. the nginx is reverse proxy and there is 2 apache web servers in 2 seperate systems.

in my machine, when i request `localhost`, it works properly. but if i request a file(for example `info.php`) that is available in 2 other servers, it can't find it and all the times it shows me local `info.php` file and never shows `info.php` files on other servers.
if I remove this file (`info.php`) from my machine, it shows me 404 error.

this is my nginx settings:

```
upstream localhost  {
    ip_hash;
    server 1.2.3.4;
    server 1.2.3.5;    
}
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass  http://localhost;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

}
```

the file `info.php` is available on 2 other servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't use `localhost` for your upstream name. Why you want to confuse a `localhost`(current machine) with a upstream localhost. Use below

```
upstream myservers  {
    ip_hash;
    server 1.2.3.4;
    server 1.2.3.5;    
}
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass  http://myservers;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

}
```

Comment: i changed it as you said, but now it takes about 60 seconds to load the apache index page, and same as before, it can't show info.php file on other servers.

Comment: Why would it show `info.php`? Your `location ~ \.php$ {` is specifically sending every php request to `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;`

Comment: so, what should i write instead? just comment it or writing something else?

Comment: comment the section